# What's a valid replacement for "None" as an empty return value in this case

Tags: haskell

I want to return None (Or Haskell's equivalent to None, rather) to this list of valid factors and whenever I encounter a number that isn't valid (a number that doesn't return a value of 0 when I run it in the modulus function along with x), I want to return None so that the list only contains the factors. There might be some errors in the code, I am new to Haskell, so you'll have to excuse sloppy code and such.

I've tried using return maybe x, since I heard that it would work, but I had no luck with it (might've been using it incorrectly, though). I also thought about using some kind of standard value and using a seoarate function to filter the values out, but I reckoned that there must be a better way.

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

checkPerfect x
    | x == sum factor x = return x
    | otherwise = return None

factor x
    | mod x [1..x-1] == 0 = return x
    | otherwise = return None

main = do
    putStrLn "Upper limit?"
    limit <- readLn
    let uncheckedNumbers = [1..limit]
    let perfectNumbersRaw = map checkPerfect uncheckedNumbers
    putStrLn ("Perfect numbers: " ++ perfectNumbersRaw)
```

Comment: What is `mod x [1..x-1]` supposed to do?

Comment: @melpomene: I would gess it has as intention something like `all (\y -> 0 == mod x y)`, so placing `== 0` everywhere. But it indeed looks like some invented syntax. Python does not understand such expression either.

Comment: To me it looks like you're missing the concept of `filter`, both in `factor` (where you're trying to apply `mod` to a list, which does not work) and in `main` (where you're using `map` instead). The only language I know that lets you express a filter using `map` is Perl (because its `map` is closer to `concatMap`). Is that where you're coming from?

Comment: It would be better to *show* your attempt at using `Maybe` than to write psuedocode involving an undefined `None` value.

Comment: I'm a little curious which language's `None` construct this refers to. For instance, in Python it's an immutable false singleton, while in Scala and Rust it's an Option value analogous to Haskell's Nothing.

Comment: I'm a python guy so that's where the "return None" comes from. I realize that the code is pretty awful, I overestimated my abilities with Haskell, which lead to this mess. I watched a video where "map" was used to apply a function to each item in a list so I decided to try and use that without looking into it much more than that. The plan behind "mod x[1..x-1]" was for it to check, along with the rest of the function, which numbers from 1 to x-1 would equal 0, meaning that they were divisors, as stated in a reply, not factors as I called them (language barrier).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually a **`Maybe a`** type is used to return a computation that can fail, or an **`Either String a`** where the `Left` constructor returns an error message.

Note that Haskell has no `return` *statement*. `return` is a function that is used for monads. Strictly speaking, you can use `return` here to wrap the result in a `Just` constructor, but it is probably more readable to do that explicitly.

That being said, your program has a lot of problems, both syntactically and semantically:

1. "*In number theory, a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its positive divisors, excluding the number itself.*" [[wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number), not factors.
2. `x == sum factor x` will not calculate the sum of the factors/divisors, since `factor` will return a single number (probably wrapped in a `Maybe`), yes, you can calculate the sum of a `Num a => Maybe a` type, but that is the sum of the only item it wraps, or `0` in case of a `Nothing`;
3. as said, you probably should not use `return` here in the first place, Haskell has no `return` *statement*;
4. you can not append a string with a list of numbers, you can however use `show :: Show a => a -> String` to convert it to a string;
5. by using `map checkPerfect` you will generate a list that contains for each item a `Just x` or a `Nothing`, you probably want to use `filter` instead.

I think it makes more sense here to return a `Bool` instead, and then filter the list:

```
checkPerfect :: Integral i => i -> Bool
checkPerfect x = x == sum (filter ((==) 0 . mod x) [1 .. x-1])
```

or as [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929256/whats-a-valid-replacement-for-none-as-an-empty-return-value-in-this-case/57929469#comment102276509_57929469) says with list comprehension:

```
checkPerfect :: Integral i => i -> Bool
checkPerfect x = x == sum [ k | k <- [1 .. x-1], mod x k == 0 ]
```

and then print the list of items with:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Upper limit?"
    limit <- readLn :: IO Int
    putStrLn ("Perfect numbers: " ++ show (filter checkPerfect [1 .. limit]))
```

If we take as limit 10'000, we get:

```
Prelude> main
Upper limit?
10000
Perfect numbers: [6,28,496,8128]
```

Comment: Alternatively: `sum [ k | k <- [1 .. x-1], mod x k == 0 ]`

Answer (score 4):

The [Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Maybe) type is the primary optional type in Haskell. For instance, you could use `Just x` and `Nothing`, or using its Monad, `return x` and `fail "not perfect"`. Note that `return` is a function of monads, moving values from pure (which is frequently the Applicative name for the same function) to monadic, and not needed when you don't need to wrap a value.